# Announcing an election for April 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Emacs Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election/3) on **April 26** to bring in two more moderators.

The timeline:

- Starting on April 19, the Community Team will post a question collection post on Meta. In it, community members can submit questions they'd like to see the nominees answer.
- Starting on April 26, users can [nominate themselves](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election/3). At that point, the questions from the above post will be collected into a questionnaire, so nominees can post their answers alongside their nominations.
- On May 3, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on May 11 (or May 18, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.